# Sugar Sync & menu bar icons

Tags: menu-bar, customization

I'm wondering if there's a way to stop SugarSync (or any app) putting itself in the OS X menu bar (top right) when launched.

Sugar Sync doesn't have this option in it's preferences.

I've managed to get Sugar Sync to appear in the Dock by going into the app's package contents and editing the property list.

But I can't figure out if a similar approach can be used to disable the menu bar item.

Comment: Have you tried using the command key and dragging the icon out of the menu bar. Hopefully the SystemUI server will remember your choice unless SugarSync insists on checking and re-inserting itself often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this for all apps.  If it's possible, it's something the app developer would've had to choose to allow and so would only be possible on an app-by-app basis.

**free idea for those who want this bad enough to go make it themselves**:

Create a library to inject into offending apps that makes [`-[NSStatusBar statusItemWithLength:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000247-BBCFGIII) return `nil`.  That *should* probably be enough to prevent apps from making status items. (along with the usual disclaimer that modifying the behavior of programs and code that you do not control is usually a very bad idea)